How is it useful in branch-and-bound to focus on lowering the global dual bound?
It seems to me that if you want branch-and-bound to be highly efficient then you should try to determine good solutions (primal bounds) as fast as possible so that you can prune more subtrees on the way, and therefore I thought that depth-first-search is the absolute go to strategy when choosing the next node to branch on. But in my lecture notes it is stated that breadth-first-search also makes sense because we are lowering the global dual bound (the worst dual bound of all active nodes). How does lowering the global dual bound help me?

No one strategy is consistently best. One argument for best-bound search is that a subtree rooted at a node with a better bound than your current node may contain a solution better than anything you will find in the subtree you are currently investigating. Like pretty much everything else in MIP solution, that is a gamble. I suspect it is more likely to pay off in models with reasonably tight bounds and less likely to pay off in models with loose bounds.

Let's say that we want to maximize. According to my lecture notes in best-bound-search we are choosing the subproblem which has the worst dual bound i.e. the highest upper bound of all subproblems. Is this right?

Yes, that is correct.
